# Definition of Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

An example question is:

> John and Jayne each choose a number (not necessarily different) from 1 to 10 inclusive. What is the probability that they each pick a number greater than $7$?

The obvious thing I would do is let $A = \text{John picking # > 7}$ and let $B = \text{Jayne Picking # > 7}$

$$P(A) = \frac{3}{10}  \qquad P(B) = \frac{3}{10}$$

Which shows:

$$P(A, B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) = \frac{9}{100}$$

But the answer shows:

> *Solution:* They can each pick a number greater than $7$ in $3$ ways. Thus the total number of ways they can pick a number greater than $7$ is $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ ways. The total number of ways they can pick their numbers is $10 \cdot 10 = 100.$ Hence, there are 9 desirable outcomes  out of 100 possible for a probability of $9/100$.

**What is the difference between the combinatorial method and the method I used?**

For a later example for picking a car, only combinatorics is used. What is this technique?

Comment: You moved from counting to probability in the middle, while the offered answer moved from counting to probability at the end.  Apart from that, there was no substantial difference.

Answer (score 2):

It is different. The first method dealt with the independence of events:

$P(A \ and\  B ) = P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

Thus you only need to calculate $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ separately and then multiply. This is usually a lot easier than calculate directly $P(A \cap B$).

The second method calculates directly $P(A \cap B)$. In this case (since outcomes are equally likely) you need to count how many outcomes represent "success" (in this case, $9$) and divide by the total number of possible outcomes.
Note that this is slightly more complicated; in a more difficult context it may be *a lot* more complicated.

Unfortunately, if you do not have independence, then it's not true that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ and you have to follow the latter strategy.
(Or try to use somehow the fact that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B \mid A)$)